# how to use selvins syncframework

Tags: android, sql-server, azure, microsoft-sync-framework

hm, i don't know where to start. i'm new to android programming. my task is synchronizing the sqlite on android with a ms sql database in windows azure. i found selvins syncframework which should do what i need.
http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/

is there anything else i need?

on his documentation, he describes how to "Adding SyncFramework to own project:".
first adding the two lines in manifest, ok, no problem.
then build providerclass which extends basecontentprovider, ok, but should it be empty? is there all for it in the basecontentprovider?
then add your database definition, ok, no problem.
then the Setup.class:

- at getServiceUrl(): which url i have to place there? the url from the database or the url from the mobile service created in windows azure or what?
- at getAuthority(): i don't have a package or class with the name Authority and there is nothing about this above.

and last
at "How to do a sync":

- at getSynUri(): does it have to be exact those two string? or do i have to replace them? if so, replace with what?
- at getContentResolver().update(): i don't understand the third parameter. does ist have to be exact that? or what does it mean and do i have to replace it?

Comment: i rewrote my question

Answer (score 0):

First i'm not sure if you can use my project with Azure ... it was created to work with [MSSFT](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e) ... for Azure you can find samples fx.: [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-android/)

> ok, but should it be empty?

It depends: BaseContentProvider provides all functionality to use simple tables ... if you wana add sql view support or join other table you have to override some methods (query,update,delete,insert)

> ... getServiceUrl() ...

Problem is that i realy do not know ... as I stated at the begin of my answer, i'm not sure if this code can work with Azure ... normaly you have to put the URL to the place where you have code from `"Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit.zip\C#\Samples\ListService"`[download from here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e/file/42361/22/Microsoft%20Sync%20Framework%20Toolkit.zip) setuped on your IIS ...

> ... getAuthority() ...

The same as you putted in AndroidManifest.xml (`provider->android:authorities="com.example.Project.Authority"`)

> ...getSynUri()...

again ... it's connected with `"Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit.zip\C#\Samples\ListService"` ... download the sample and you'll see the file `DefaultScopeSyncService.SVC` so first parameter of getSyncUri will be `DefaultScopeSyncService` (you can have multiple services there) .... second parameter is the scope from `DefaultScopeSyncService.SVC.cs` from line `config.SetEnableScope("DefaultScope")` ...

> ...getContentResolver().update()...

Actually it should be `call` not `update`, but since there is no such method in API < 11 i used `update` ... if you call `update` with special URI(getSynUri()), BaseContentProvider will call sync code, the third parameter is used for templete scopes filters on server side (again see `DefaultScopeSyncService.SVC.cs` line `config.AddFilterParameterConfiguration("userid", "User", "@ID", typeof(System.Guid));` this become parameter like `"userid=some-guid"` on android side

Comment: thanks for your explanation. i think i have to search for another solution. do you have a suggestion for me?